# SQL and Joining

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Read below and navigate to this url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e825f to get a better understanding of my issue.

I have been trying to get this query right for awhile but cannot figure it out. I have been trying to join two tables to get the right data, but maybe I think I should make a third table. See my situation below:

I have two tables:

1. sites table - lists all websites that I have. See below for how I created my table

   ```
   create table sites
   (
     id int,
     websiteName varchar(50),
     url varchar(50),
     mobile_id varchar(50),
     is_responsive varchar(1)    
   );
   ```
2. Mobiles table - lists which websites are mobile and has a mobile url

   ```
   create table mobile
   (
    id int,
    mobile_url varchar(50)
   );
   ```

The `sites` table and `mobiles` table are related through the foreign key in the `sites` table called [mobile_id].

The is_responsive column located in the [sites table] is a bit field that holds a 1, stating this site is fully responsive, or a 0 stating this site is non-responsive.

MY GOAL:
To build a query that returns all mobile websites and responsive websites. I tried using three tables but that did not work. Originally my third table held all responsive websites, but adding another table does not make sense. Also I found  a solution using the UNION statement, but I do not want to use that.

Comment: sorry please see this url: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c1dae

Comment: Can you explain your goal little more detail or probably give a sample data.

Comment: this link does not suffice? Do you need more sample data at this url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c1dae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the specification... "all mobile websites and responsive websites"...

I will suggest that something of this form may return the resultset you specified.

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.websiteName
     , s.url
     , s.mobile_id
     , s.is_responsive
     , IF(m.mobile_url IS NOT NULL,'1','0') AS is_mobile
  FROM sites s
  LEFT
  JOIN mobile m
    ON m.mobile_url = s.mobile_id 
 WHERE m.mobile_url IS NOT NULL
    OR s.is_responsive = '1'
```

We'd normally expect the foreign key to reference the id column, but given that you say you have a foreign key (and don't specify which column is the target), and the foreign key column has a datatype of VARCHAR(50), we are going to guess that this references the `mobile_url` column, since that is the only column in mobile that has a matching datatype.

If the intent is to reference the `id` column, then the datatype of the `mobile_id` should *match* the datatype of the `id` column, and the join predicate would be:

```
    ON m.id = s.mobile_id
```

Also, each of your tables should have a PRIMARY KEY, or at least a UNIQUE KEY defined.table.

The table definitions I would use, based on what you posted, would be something along these lines:

```
 CREATE TABLE mobile
 ( id           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
 , mobile_url   VARCHAR(50)                       COMMENT 'mobile website URL'
 ) ;

 CREATE TABLE site
 ( id           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
 , websiteName  VARCHAR(50)                       COMMENT 'website name'
 , url          VARCHAR(50)                       COMMENT 'website URL'
 , mobile_id    INT UNSIGNED                      COMMENT 'FK ref mobile.id'
 , is_responsive TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0    COMMENT 'boolean'
 , CONSTRAINT FK_site_mobile (mobile_id) REFERENCES mobile(id)
 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
select sites.* from sites
left join mobile on mobile.id = sites.mobile_id
where (sites.is_responsive = '1' or mobile_id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from sites
left outer join mobile on sites.mobile_id = mobile.id
where sites.is_responsive = '1' or mobile.mobile_url is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mobile_url from from mobile 
union
select url from sites when is_responsive = 1
```

Comment: "Also I found a solution using the UNION statement, but I do not want to use that." -OP

Comment: Why do you think it is "over use"?

Answer (score 0):

The program in the sample is that no mobile site is responsive but the code you wrote first is working.

```
 select sites.* from sites
 inner join mobile on sites.mobile_id = mobile.id 
 where sites.is_responsive = '1'
```